# How to use NSDecimalNumber to convert latitude and longitude in IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, mapkit, cllocation, nsdecimalnumber

I would like to show my position on the map, I'm using `CLLocation` for doing it

Here is my code:

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;
coordinate.latitude = latitude;
coordinate.longitude = longitude;
```

With `latitude` and `longitude` is float type and get from database
But when i convert to float value so i get wrong value:

```
float latitude = [myLatString floatValue];
```

and result:

> myLatString : 10.861714
>
> float value : 10.8617144

So i can't load to my mapview with above values.

I searched on google, someone said use `NSDecimalNumber` but how to work `NSDecimalNumber` with `CLLocation`??

Please help me

Comment: What were you expecting to get? And why are you storing numbers as strings in your database instead of just numbers?

Answer (score 2):

Use of `NSDecimalNumber` to convert `NSString` to `float`.

```
NSString *myLatString = @"10.8617144";
NSDecimalNumber *decimalPoint = [[NSDecimalNumber alloc] initWithString: myLatString];
float latitude = decimalPoint.floatValue;
```

Comment: Really, just a down vote. To the down voter have you read what OP required here. And give a comment if you think that this is wrong answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use doubles. Latitude and longitude are `CLLocationDegree`, which are double.

Also best to use [CLLocationCoordinate2DMake](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CoreLocationFunctions/index.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CLLocationCoordinate2DMake):

`CLLocationCoordinate2D loc = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake([myLatString doubleValue], [myLngString doubleValue]);`